# Mapping values with a condition, Pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, replace, conditional-statements, where-clause

```
        State   City
0  California      1
1  California      2
2    Lousiana      1
3    Virginia      2
```

```
dic = {1 : LA, 2 : SF}
```

I am trying to map the dictionary I have on the table with the condition that the "State" is California.

**The expected result is:**

```
        State   City
0  California     LA
1  California     SF
2    Lousiana      1
3    Virginia      2
```

I have tried,

```
df['City'] = df['City'].where(df['State']=='California').map(dic)
```

but I get:

```
        State   City
0  California     LA
1  California     SF
2    Lousiana    NaN
3    Virginia    NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
dic = {1 : 'LA', 2 : 'SF'}

m = df['State'].eq('California')

df.loc[m, 'City'] = df.loc[m, 'City'].map(dic)
```

A fix of your approach (but less efficient than above) would be:

```
df['City'] = df['City'].mask(df['State']=='California', df['City'].map(dic))
```

output:

```
        State City
0  California   LA
1  California   SF
2    Lousiana    1
3    Virginia    2
```